# how to move a character to a certain inputted index

Tags: python-3.x, text-editor

I am trying to make my own text editor where it asks for a file and prints a > that can then be moved to the specified index of the line so that it can then delete a character. I don't know the best way to move it. So far I have

```
def print_file(data, cursor):
"""Prints the file contents (data), with the cursor in the right place."""

# Variable fm will store the formatted representation
# of the file with position information, etc.
fm = ""
pos = 0

# Break the "file" (represented by a string) up into lines.
lines = data.split("\n")

for x, line in enumerate(lines):
    length = len(line)

    if length != 0:
        # Edge case for the end of the "file".
        if data[-1] != "\n" and x == len(lines) - 1:
            length -= 1


        fm += str("{0:70} |{1:3d}:{2:3d}|\n".format(line, pos, pos + length))

        # If the cursor points to char on this line add it. 
        if pos <= cursor <= pos + length:
            fm += " " * (cursor - pos)  + "^\n" 

    # Start at the next character.
    pos += length + 1
print(fm, end="")
#end of function 

def move_cursor(location):
    """Moves the cursor to the right location"""

#end of function

cursor = 0
is_open = False
is_modified = False
file = str(input(">open "))

#Open filename
file == "(filename)"
file = open(file, "r")
file_data = file.read()
print_file(file_data, cursor)
command = str(input("> "))

#Move position
if command == "move(int)":
    move_cursor(location)
```

I think the best way would be to make a function and then call it inside the loop, but am unsure how to actually get it to move to the index....

Comment: please, fix indentation

Comment: @AzatIbrakov is that better? What indention is off? It should be two different functions, and then coding below that starts with 'cursor = 0' I'm really new to python.

Comment: it's not clear, what is insides of `print_file` and  `move_cursor` functions

Comment: @AzatIbrakov `print_file` goes until `print(fm, end="")` then it starts the next function. `move_cursor` right now only has the description inside the three quotes. After that, it goes outside of the functions and is regular code

Comment: then you need add indentation level for functions insides, for empty function add `pass`